# How to find projects not running on .Net Core

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio

I have a list of projects in my org.(More than 1000) and I want to find projects which dont have .NET Core installed.
I can try to search on Azure DevOps (ADO) and see the csproj (or something) to see which projects dont have .Net Core but what to search.
I tried searching netstandard2.1, but I read somewhere that it can also be a part of .Net Core.

Can someone help out in this ?

Comment: This is something you can only make a best attempt at, not guarantee that you identified all of them. With that in mind, did you start by looking at the documentation on what constitutes an older .NET framework target versus a modern .NET/.NET Core target? i.e. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks

Comment: @gunr2171 I can see that for .netCore>=2.x, I will have targetframework as netcoreappx.y or netstandardx.y. But when to know that this is not a netCore ? All the other situations are not core ?

Comment: @DanielMann Yes, having best attempt is ok. I tried looking into the link, but I got confused. WHat table should I be looking into ? `Supported target frameworks and .Net Core there ?` ?

Comment: The csproj file is text.  Easy way is to open the csproj and check the target version being used.